# Split text data by number

Tags: apex, split

I need to split 10 digit number using apex. This is my input addresses

IDOC error for  partner 0001204140 team

My output like below:

0001204140

Comment: do we have any fixed pattern for it?? means any specific format???

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

For numeric 10 digit value, regex pattern is `[0-9]{10}`.

Following code works perfectly for me.

```
// First, instantiate a new Pattern object "MyPattern"
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('[0-9]{10}');

String myString = 'IDOC error for partner 0001204140 team';
List<String> lstStr = myString.split(' ');
String finalString = '';
for(String str:lstStr)
{
    System.debug('str=' + str);

    // Then instantiate a new Matcher object "MyMatcher"
    Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(str);

    // You can use the system static method assert to verify the match
    System.debug(MyMatcher.matches());
    if(MyMatcher.matches())
    {
        finalString = str;
        break;
    }
}

System.debug('finalString=' + finalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

If thats the only number in you string then you can use isNumeric() to find numbers.

```
String str = 'IDOC error for partner 0001204140 team';
String numericString = '';
integer strLength = str.length();
for(integer i =0;i<str.length();i++){
    String s= str.mid(i,1);
    if(s.isNumeric()){
        numericString +=s;
    }
}
System.debug('Number is: ' + numericString);
```

But if its possible that you have numbers in multiple place then you need a fix format or a better regex.